# Create a list using a for in XQuery 1.0

Tags: xml, xquery

I would like to create a list of element using a for like in this example:

```
for $ingr in distinct-values(//Ingredient/Name)
let $res := (
  for $res2 in //Restaurant
  return if( some $ingr2 in $res2/Dish/Ingredient/Name satisfies $ingr2 eq $ingr )
    then( $res2 )
    else()
  )
return $ingr, $res
```

What I want to obtain is: `For each ingredient return the list of restaurants that use it`.
I really don't understand where is the problem?

Here you can see an example: http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/0c8f9699df404020afd07ff9f9517a46

It keep saying: `ERROR - Variable $res has not been declared`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression was read as `(for ... let ... return $ingr), ($res)`. Which means that `$res` at the end is considered a different expression separate from the previous FLWOR expression, hence the undeclared variable error.

You can simply use parentheses to alter this unwanted grouping :

```
for $ingr in distinct-values(//Ingredient/Name)
let $res := (
  for $res2 in //Restaurant
  return if( some $ingr2 in $res2/Dish/Ingredient/Name satisfies $ingr2 eq $ingr )
    then( $res2 )
    else()
  )
return ($ingr, $res)
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/b184b838399782828a489e7024ba638f)</kbd>**

Answer (score 3):

As har07 correctly points out, parentheses are needed to get the final reference of `$res` into the scope of the FLWOR expression. However I think the query as you wrote it is overly complex, in particular the quantified expression can be replaced by just a path expression. Here is a simpler variant:

```
for $ingr in distinct-values(//Ingredient/Name)
return ($ingr, //Restaurant[Dish/Ingredient/Name = $ingr])
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in defining $res2 in your code
you have to change the for loop to let the child node inside the parent node

```
for $res2 in //Restaurant

   let $Ingredient := distinct-values(//Ingredient/Name/data()) 
                  (:This is a list of ingredients :)
   let $ingr := if (some $ingr2 in $Ingredient
satisfies (contains(lower-case($res2//Ingredient/Name), $ingr2)))
        then( $res2 )
        else()
      )
    return $ingr, $res2
```

Comment: This code gives me this error: `ERROR - System function data#0 is not available with this host language/version`

Comment: you have to remove the {data()} from the second line of the code